# Style UITableViewCell text using UIAppearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiappearance

I've got a tableView of type `Plain` containing one PrototypeCell of Type `Custom`. The prototype cells class is the default `UITableViewCell` class, as I'm NOT using any specialized subclass.[image: TableViewCell settings...]
The problem is, that I simply want to style the textlabels contained within the default `UITableViewCell` (textLabel and detailTextLabel) by using `UIAppearance` for iOS7.

I've tried

```
[[UILabel appearance]] appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setTextColor:UIColor.redColor];
```

to no avail. I know that the Apple documentation states, that the default labels mentioned above are always created with the default font and with textcolor black. However I expected, that styling the UILabels with appearance should work out. Any ideas regarding that topic?

REMARK: I know it's possible to set the textcolors using`cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor`, but I want to define the styling once.

Comment: Why don't you set the text color of the label in the interface builder? No need to do that in code (if you want to change it on every cell, as you mentioned)

Comment: I'm not using a custom label. I'm trying to style the cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLabel objects. Thank you for the comment, I'll add that information to my question. As far as I know there's no possibility in IB to set this value directly.

Comment: Yes there is a way in IB. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use this two labels, you don't have a `Custom` cell but a `Subtitle` cell. And still you can change the properties of these labels in the IB.

Just double click on the labels to change their properties. (Or have a look in `ContentView` on the left):

[image: Subtitle Cell]
[image: text label properties]

Comment: Thank's, that did the trick. Strangely enough using the "Subtitle" Style also enabled the use of the UIAppearance proxy as it should. Strange, that this doesn't work when selecting "Custom" and settings values for the "textLabel". (I noticed, that the descriptionLabel wasn't visible when using "Custom"; makes sense)